# Date function format php

Tags: php, date, datetime, gmt

Please can anybody help !!

I want the date to be in the following format

```
Wed Oct 09 2013 14:48:26 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) //this one is what jquery Date(); returns
```

but I am getting it in

```
Wed Oct 09 2013 15:42:38 Asia/Kolkata+0530 (IST)
```

I am using

```
date('D M d Y H:i:s eO (T)');
```

The problem is jQuery is returning me date with **GMT+0530** and PHP is returning it with **Asia/Kolkata+0530**

**Edit**

I am placing a timer in my code, which displays logged in since, so on login I set the current date time in session using PHP date function as written above , but the problem is the new Date() function of jQuery returns date in format other than the date in PHP. please find the code below

PHP Code:

```
date_default_timezone_set("GMT+0530");
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = date('D M d Y H:i:s eO (T)'); // returns Wed Oct 09 2013 15:42:38 Asia/Kolkata+0530 (IST)
```

JS Code: `//JS date function returns time as Wed Oct 09 2013 14:48:26 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        if($('#logged').val()!=''){
            var pageVisisted = new Date($_SESSION['loggedin']); 

            setInterval(function() {
                var timeOnSite = new Date() - pageVisisted;

                var secondsTotal = timeOnSite / 1000;
                var hours = Math.floor(secondsTotal / 3600);
                var minutes = Math.floor(secondsTotal / 60) % 3600;
                var seconds = Math.floor(secondsTotal)  % 60;
                var showtime = "Logged in Since ";
                if(hours>0){
                    showtime = showtime + hours + " hours and ";
                }
                showtime = showtime + minutes + " mins";
                document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = showtime;
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
```

Comment: This might be helpful to you.[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245556/error-in-showing-outlook-appointment-time-using-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245556/error-in-showing-outlook-appointment-time-using-php)

Comment: @KishorSubedi well that didnt help, thnx btw

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  You haven't described the problem very well.  Please show both the javascript code, and the php code.  And which direction are you going?  I can't tell from your question.

Comment: Please also realize that you have set yourself up for an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/201534) by just asking for wanting to convert formats, rather than describing the actual use case.

Comment: @MattJohnson please find the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a ton of different ways in PHP you can solve your problem. Just use the date and time related extensions like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
$datetime = new DateTime("now");

// result: Thu Oct 24 2013 16:34:14 Europe/Berlin+0200 (CEST) 
echo $datetime->format("D M d Y H:i:s eO (T)");
```

The second example solving your problem:

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Calcutta');
$datetime = new DateTime("now", $timezone);

// result: Thu Oct 24 2013 20:04:14 GMT+0530
echo $datetime->format("D M d Y H:i:s \G\M\TO");
```

For further examples just have a look for the php time and date related objects and functions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Comment: thank you so much !! I had no idea of date time, I was just going again and again for date function only

Comment: Bounty will be awarded in 5 hours !!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to force `GMT+0000`, then hard code it:

```
echo date('D M d Y H:i:s \G\M\TO (e)');
```

As far as `IST` vs `India Standard Time`, I don't think there is a simple way.

```
$tz_map = [
  'IST' => 'India Standard Time'
];
echo strtr(date('D M d Y H:i:s \G\M\TO (e)'), $tz_map);
```

Using `T` instead of `E` might be easier if you want to do a search/replace map.

Comment: but I want the timezone dynamically, PHP date is returning me Asia/Kolkata+0530 and jquery GMT+0530 , and its giving problem in calculations

Comment: O is GMT time, so I think date('D M d Y H:i:s \G\M\TO (T)') is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Well I resolved it with the worst way possibly

```
$date = str_replace('Asia/Kolkata+0530', 'GMT+0530', date('D M d Y H:i:s eO (T)'));
```